# Question related to components of vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, kinematics, vectors

**Question:**

> A uniform electric field $E$ is created between two parallel, charged plates. An electron enters the field symmetrically between the plates with a speed $v_o$. The length of each plate is $L$. Find the angle of deviation of the path of the electron as it comes out of the field.

**Doubt:**

I calculated the acceleration in the y direction as $a=\frac{eE}{m}$. (assuming the plates to be parallel to x axis.)

Also, the time for which the electron will be inside will be $t=\frac{L}{v_o}$

Now, the value of the angle ($\theta$) can be calculated by using $\tan\theta=\frac{v_y}{v_x}$ and the answer can be obtained.

**But if I do the same for displacement, i.e. $\tan\theta=\frac{S_y}{S_x}$, I am getting a different answer. Why?**

Comment: What do you call the "displacement" here, particularly what are $s_y, s_x$?

Comment: $S_x$ is the component of displacement of the electron in the x direction and it will be equal to L. Whereas $S_y$ is the component of displacement of electron in y direction. It will be equal to $\frac{1}{2} at^2$ as initial velocity of electron along y axis is 0. $a$ and $t$ are acceleration and time respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calculating two different angles. See picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They should be different as the speed along y does not go from zero to its final value instantaneously, it linearly increases when the electron goes between the two electrodes, following a parabola. The slope of the parabola at the output of the two electrodes does not intercept the parabola at zero.

If you make a drawing it should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no discrepancy here. Let me illustrate:

[image: physics]
The velocity is instantaneous (the blue arrow), but the position is only the position of the electron relative to the start position. So you don't expect the vectors to point in the same direction.

Remember, uniform acceleration gives parabolas.